# Compare AccountId to array slice in pallets dispatchable call

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

I have an accountId type from `origin` extracted as `let who = ensure_signed(origin)?`.

In addition I also have a `expected: Vec<u8>` which is expected to be equal to the address inside `who`. But am only being sure by logging both the value. How actually can i compare them inside `ensure!` (or `assert_eq`) or is there any other method provided to do so?

Is there a way to convert one of these value to other type and make use of `Ord/Eq` trait.

Or there exist some function that can ensure this condition when provided with origin and expected array bytes.

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to determine what exactly you are doing here, but I'm going to take a guess that `expected` is an input in your transaction.

Firstly you should not be storing addresses as type `Vec<u8>` which is technically a string. Addresses should use the `T::AccountId`type.

Secondly you do not need to check that the account that signed the transaction is an expected address, unless you are comparing it to an address that you have stored previously. Even in that case the storage type would still have to be `T::AccountId`. Then you could compare them.

Comment: Actuallt `expected` is recived in function paramater from front-end so I was trying to figure out a way to compare that with address inside `AccountId::Signed`. Any alternate method you would have done it better?

Comment: This makes no sense. You do not need to compare a submitted address to the one that signed the transaction. Just use the one that signed the transaction. Secondly if you want to use any address as an argument in a function the type should be `T::AccountId` not `Vec<u8>` as stated in my answer.

Comment: Our custom logic requires us to do the first one, I will consider about changing type to T::AccountId. Thanks mate

Comment: `Vec<u8>` is dangerous to use - as an input it has no bounds and is (in effect) a string field. This means that any malicious actor could feasibly send an arbitrarily large string in the `expected:` parameter as a transaction and break your chain. This is why you should not be using an inappropriate type nor one that cannot be readily rejected.

Comment: Argument to be made tho. What approach would you suggest. I was trying to receive a raw message and wallet address ( other than the wallet I am targeting for ). Any good idea?